# A question on a certain transformation of a normal random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

I have to solve the following exercise:

> Suppose  $X\sim N(\mu,1)$ and consider $Y=\dfrac{1-\Phi(X)}{\phi(X)}$,
>   where $\phi,\Phi$ are the pdf and cdf of the standard normal
>   distribution with mean zero. Compute the expected value of $Y$ in terms of $\mu$.

Please give me some hints only.

Comment: Convergence is not your friend. BTW, the ratio is known as Mills ratio. And you should define your notation, since I have had to guess.

Comment: This came in an exam paper in a semester where convergence is not taught. This was the question verbatim. I wanted to make sure I know the symbols and what they mean.

Comment: Is the variable $Y$ really defined as $\frac{1-\Phi(X)}{\phi(X)}$, or the density of $Y$ is defined as $\frac{1-\Phi(x)}{\phi(x)}$?

Comment: The variable Y is defined as that.

Comment: And $\phi,\Phi$ are the pdf and cdf of $X$?

Comment: No, they are the pdf and cdf of the standard normal variable.

Comment: Well, that changes things

Comment: wolfies, the answer is $1/\mu$. Any general form of Mill's theorem?

Comment: I slightly modified the question for the sake of clarity. I hope you don't mind.

Comment: No no, certainly not. I presumed that $\Phi$ and $\phi$ are well-known. Even they were not defined in the question paper. So it is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $Z$ be a standard normal variable. Since:
$$\frac{1-\Phi(x)}{\phi(x)}=\frac{1}{\mathbb{E}[Z\,|\,Z>x]}=e^{x^2/2}\int_{x}^{+\infty}e^{-z^2/2}\,dz=\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-zx}e^{-z^2/2}\,dz$$
we have that:
$$\mathbb{E}[Y]=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-(x-\mu)^2/2}\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-zx}e^{-z^2/2}\,dz\,dx\tag{1} $$
so:
$$\mathbb{E}[Y]=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-x^2/2}e^{-z^2/2}e^{-z(x+\mu)}\,dz\,dx \tag{2}$$
and switching the order of integration we get:
$$\mathbb{E}[Y] = \int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-z\mu}\,dz =\frac{1}{\mu}\tag{3}$$
as wanted.

Comment: "Please give me some hints only."

Comment: @Did: yep, I know, probably I went too much into details, but this is all about the Fubini-Tonelli theorem applied to $(2)$, and "Hint: apply the Fubini-Tonelli theorem" meets an obvious reply: "To what?" :)

Comment: I do not know the Fubini theorem so this was probably out of my reach.

Comment: @yedaynara: maybe you know it under a pseudonym, but it is just the theorem that allows to swap the integral wrt $dz$ and the integral wrt $dx$.

Comment: By the way, the very first identity in the answer is wrong, since, actually, $$\frac{1-\Phi(x)}{\phi(x)}=\frac1{\mathbb{E}[Z\,|\,Z>x]}.$$ Fortunately, the formula involving $Z$ is not used at all in the rest of the answer (only the integral one, right next to it).

Comment: @Did: oh, thank you for noticing. Now fixing.

Comment: You might want to get rid of Z altogether, as my previous comment hinted at.

Comment: @Did: I prefer to leave it there, just for remarking that $\Phi,\phi$ are not the cdf and pdf of $X$. An interesting related question is now: what is $\operatorname{Var}[Y]$? and the pdf of $Y$?